# Do `()`, `{}`, `:` and `[]` in MongoDB have their meanings inherited from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The language of MongoDB shell is based on Javascript. In the following example,

```
> document = ({"Type": "Book", "Title" : "Definitive Guide to MongoDB 3rd ed., The",  
"ISBN" : "978-1-4842-1183-0", "Publisher" : "Apress", "Author" : ["Hows, David", "Plugge, 
Eelco", "Membrey, Peter", "Hawkins, Tim"] } )

> db.media.insertOne(document)
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

The first assignment also works in `node` for Javascript.

So is it correct that  `()`, `{}`, `:` and `[]` in the assignment have their meanings inherited from Javascript?

If they come from Javascript, what do they mean respectively?

Thanks.

Comment: `{}, : and []` Are part of javascript object/array notation syntax

Comment: [Based on the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/): "The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB.".  Those don't just come *from* JavaScript.  They *are* JavaScript.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. What does `()` mean in the assignment?

Comment: Depends which one. Invokes function on last line and on first line is redundant.

Comment: @Ben In the assignment, the `( )` is the [JavaScript grouping operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) (Search page for "grouping".)  It serves no purpose in your code.

Comment: @char The first command for assignment. Even if the `()` is redundant, what does it mean  actually?

Comment: Used for setting order of  precedence in evaluating more complex statements...pretty much the same as in math